# sql database engine is not working anymore, cant connect

Tags: sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio for my project.I had a database and I could connect to it every time.Now, every time I try to connect to the database engine, it gives me the error from the image.I don't know what to do..It worked perfectly last week.[image]

Comment: Is MSSQLSERVER service is running?

Comment: press `WIN+R` (`WIN` = that windows button), type `services.msc` start looking for anything with term SQL there.. is there any of them? can you post what are they, and their status (running or not)?

Comment: MSSQLSERVER wasnt running.I fixed that and now I can connect to the database.Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the services SQL Server and SQL Server Browser

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by using . in servername? I guess the name isn't correct

[image]